# Integrating Hippo CMS with spring MVC

Tags: java

I have to integrate hippo CMS with spring MVC and I can't find any tutorial doing this .please can you help me to find one ? or just tell me how can I start ?

Answer (score 2):

check out this page : http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/web-application/spring-mvc-bridge.html. If you have any questions, our community forum at http://www.onehippo.org/library/about/cms-forums.html is a great place to get answers from architects/developers from Hippo or its partners and customers